# Upload image using codeigniter controller

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
public function add_software()
{   
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error-form">',   
'</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 
'required|min_length[4]|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('licence', 'Licence.', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('platform', 'Platform', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('developers', 'Developer',     
'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('link', 'Developer Website', 
'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat', 'Category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('logo', 'Software Logo', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/add_software');
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/footer');
    } else {
    //Setting values for tabel columns
    $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');
    $data['description'] = $this->input->post('desc');
    $data['licence']     = $this->input->post('licence');
    $data['platform']    = $this->input->post('platform');
    $data['developers']  = $this->input->post('developers');
    $data['link']        = $this->input->post('link');
    $data['category']    = $this->input->post('cat');
    $data['logo']    = $this->input->post('logo');

    /////////////////////////////////
    //set preferences

    $config = array(
    'upload_path' => '' .base_url(). '/assets/img/logo/',
    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => "4096000", 
    'max_height' => "1024",
    'max_width' => "1024"
    );
            //load upload class library

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
           $this->upload->data();
           $this->upload->do_upload();
    /////////////////////////////////
    //Transfering data to Model
    $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
    $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
    //Loading View
    redirect('admin/view_softwares', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

This is my codeigniter controller function. Using this function, I can add data to the database. But, I am unable to upload image. Even `upload_files` is enabled in `php.ini`. I tried resolving this problem all day long, but all in vain.
I have not used `enctype` in my html form because when I use `enctype`, I get the below error:

```
undefined Index filename
```

Comment: try  'upload_path' => './assets/img/logo/',

Comment: You have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for uploading a file and Use **$image_info = $this->upload->do_upload("name_of_input_type_file");**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend i wil give code that i have done for uploading image.This surely work.
You can refer this.Any doubt,please ask,i wil help you

```
public function uploadImage() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));  
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/b2bcategory';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1768';
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;
        if (isset($_FILES['catimage']['name'])) {
            $filename = "-" . $_FILES['catimage']['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . $filename;
        }
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $field_name = "catimage";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->input->post('selsub')) {
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('catimage')) {
                //no file uploaded or failed upload
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $dat = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->resize($dat['upload_data']['full_path'],           $dat['upload_data']['file_name']);
            }
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            if (empty($dat['upload_data']['file_name'])) {
                $catimage = '';
            } else {
                $catimage = $dat['upload_data']['file_name'];
            }
            $data = array(            
                'ctg_image' => $catimage,
                'ctg_dated' => time()
            );
            $this->b2bcategory_model->form_insert($data);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome dear.Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong.

```
'upload_path' => '' .base_url(). '/assets/img/logo/',
```

> Note: Make sure your upload path "assets folder" is in the main directory out side of
>   application folder. You also may need to set folder permissions.

Try

```
'upload_path' => FCPATH . 'assets/img/logo/'
```

or just

```
'upload_path' => './assets/img/logo/'
```

To access file info after upload success [preferences](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences)

```
$image_info = $this->upload->data();

echo $image_info['file_name'];
```

Or Through Model

```
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data,  $image_info = array());
```